# `systemctl reboot --boot-loader-entry` not working with certain bootloader entries

Tags: linux-mint, systemd-boot

I'm trying to setup an easy way to reboot my system into a specified boot-loader, whether that's Windows or another version of Linux. On my test system, I've installed **systemd-boot** and created entries for each kernel that's currently installed. Here is what **systemctl** recognizes as boot-loader entries:

```
$ sudo systemctl reboot --boot-loader-entry=help
Linuxmint-20.1-5.4.0-58-generic.conf
Linuxmint-20.1-5.4.0-66-generic.conf
Linuxmint-20.1.conf                   <--- this is the default entry
auto-reboot-to-firmware-setup
```

All of these entries work when selected manually from the systemd-boot menu. However, when called from `sudo systemctl reboot --boot-loader-entry=`, the only ones that work are the default and firmware entries. If there's an error on the reboot, it's not being shown. As soon as the boot menu pops up, it's back to the default entry.

Here are a couple of the boot-loader conf files:

```
# cat Linuxmint-20.1-5.4.0-58-generic.conf
title   Linux Mint 20.1 ulyssa (5.4.0-58-generic)
linux   /Linuxmint-20.1/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic
initrd  /Linuxmint-20.1/initrd.img-5.4.0-58-generic
options root=UUID=a67973ca-bd17-4f40-aba6-160fef33086a rw rootflags=subvol=@ iommu=pt

# cat Linuxmint-20.1.conf
title   Linux Mint 20.1 ulyssa (5.4.0-67-generic)
linux   /Linuxmint-20.1/vmlinuz-5.4.0-67-generic
initrd  /Linuxmint-20.1/initrd.img-5.4.0-67-generic
options root=UUID=a67973ca-bd17-4f40-aba6-160fef33086a rw rootflags=subvol=@ iommu=pt
```

Could it be related to my `loader.conf` settings?

```
# cat loader.conf 
timeout 10
console-mode auto
editor yes
random-seed-mode always

default Linuxmint-20.1.conf
```

UPDATE #1: using `systemctl reboot --boot-loader-entry=auto-windows` on my main system also works.

Comment: So you have Linuxmint and Windows. Dualboot. Linuxmint you have 3 different kernels with same root partition. Is my understanding correct? I tried to reproduce the issue with triple boot Arch Fedora and Ubuntu, but it worked.